# c# socket check connection

Tags: c#, sockets, asyncsocket

I'm trying to establish a socket connection to a host/ip address for a specific port. The main things I try to achieve are:

- get the response time in milliseconds for booth success/fail connection
- use a custom timeout for example 5 seconds (5000)

So basically if I specify a host name like `google.com` and port `80` this should check if connection works, the same if I specify `173.194.70.101` and port `80` it should work.

If I specify for example host name like `google.com` and port `7788` this should not work because that port is not open. If I specify IP: `173.194.70.101` and port ´7788´ this should not work.

If I specify some random host like `sdfzsdfaklsf.com` and port `7788` this should not work because the host doesn't exist.

For all the cases above I need the response time for all success/fail ...

I ended up with this code and seams to work fine, however I would like to ask if this is a proper way of doing it?

```
     public string CheckConnection(string ipAddressOrHostName, string portName)
    {
        Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
        timer.Start();
        Socket server = null;
        string elapsed = string.Empty;

        try
        {

            IPHostEntry hostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(ipAddressOrHostName);

            IPAddress ipAddress = hostEntry.AddressList[0];

            IPEndPoint ip = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, Convert.ToInt32(portName));

            server = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            IAsyncResult result = server.BeginConnect(ip, null, null);

            result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(5000, true);

            timer.Stop();

            elapsed = timer.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString();


            if (!server.Connected)
            {                    
                server.Close();
                throw new Exception();
            }
            else
            {   
                string status = string.Format("Connected succesfully to: {0} in: {1} milliseconds", server.RemoteEndPoint.ToString(), elapsed);                   
                server.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                server.Close();

                return status;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            timer.Stop();

            elapsed = timer.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString();

            return string.Format("Connection failed to: {0}:{1} in: {2} milliseconds", ipAddressOrHostName, portName, elapsed);                     
        }

    }
```

Comment: I would improve your exception handling. Catching a generic exception and treating as a specific network/connection failure is not recommended. Also try putting your close/shutdown/stop calls into a 'finally' block.... beside that, I think that looks fine..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty good. A few points:

1. Catch a more **specific type of exception** and test it. You don't want to catch unrelated stuff or hide bugs.
2. **Start the timer** *after* you have completed the DNS resolution.
3. `throw new Exception` is not so good because **exceptions are not meant as control flow**. Restructure the method to not need this hack.
4. You might want to use **tasks** instead of `IAsyncResult`. No functional change, just more modern style.
5. You have **redundancy** in a few places (e.g. the duplicate closing, duplicate ToString).
6. **Parse the port outside of the method**. It does not belong there. In fact, if the port is unparsable you will trigger a perceived timeout at the moment because an exception will be thrown. That's what I am warning you of with point (1). Using exceptions too much has caused a bug that you maybe would never have known about because it was hidden.

Comment: Can you please tell how can I implement async await instead of IAsyncResult?

Comment: I think that's out of scope for this question. Search for "await socket" to find the answer. If you have further questions let me know.

Comment: I did implemented async-await instead of IAsyncResult, but I loose the control of the custom timeout which by default is 20 seconds i think ... but anyway thanks for your comments!

Comment: To be clear I do not recommend await here. I just recommended tasks without await (e.g. Task.Wait(5000)). But that is just a weak preference.